# ActionView::MissingTemplate - AJAX related error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionview

The left column div is a list of lists. I'm trying to use AJAX to add a new list. I'm following the screencast http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised but I am getting an error. It seems to be a problem with the create action. Please note that when I refresh the page, the new list appears so it is getting created and added to the database.

Here is the 500 internal server error I get (from lists file using POST in Network tab) when I try submitting the name of the new list:

**ActionView::MissingTemplate in Lists#create**

Showing /Users/jeff/Documents/rails_projects/grocery-beta/app/views/lists/create.js.erb where line #3 raised:

```
Missing partial lists/list with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:  * "/Users/jeff/Documents/rails_projects/grocery-beta/app/views"  * "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-2.2.3/app/views"
```

**Extracted source (around line #3):**

```
1: $('#new_list').remove();2: $('#new_link').show();3: $('#lists').append('<%= j render(@list) %>');

app/views/lists/create.js.erb:3:in `_app_views_lists_create_js_erb__870295634789681698_70311054285220'app/controllers/lists_controller.rb:36:in `create'
```

Here is my `create.js.erb` file:

```
$('#new_list').remove();
$('#new_link').show();
$('#lists').append('<%= j render(@list) %>');
```

Here is the **create action** from my`lists_controller.rb` file:

```
def create
    @list = List.create!(params[:list])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_url }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Here is my **root page**, `home.html.erb`:

```
<div id="main-left">
    <div id="main-left-1">
        <%= link_to 'Add List', new_list_path, class: "button", id: "new_link", remote: true %>
    </div>
    <ul id="lists" data-update-url="<%= sort_lists_url %>">
      <% @lists.each do |list| %>
        <%= content_tag_for :li, list do %>
          <%= link_to list.name, list, :remote => true, :class => "link" %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my `_form.html.erb` parial file:

```
<%= form_for @list, remote: true do |f| %>

  <% if @list.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@list.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this list from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @list.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here is my `application.html.erb` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Grocery List
        </title>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
        <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Serif|Gabriela' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="wrapper">
        <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
        <div id="main">
            <%= yield %>
        </div><!-- main -->
      </div><!-- wrapper -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my `new.js.erb` file:

```
$('#new_link').hide().after('<%= j render("form") %>');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems a problem in `render(@list)`. Rails can't find appropriate template to render.

Suggested revise:

In `create.js.erb`

```
# The task is to rendering a piece of "list" and add it to exist "lists"
# Suppose the template of this piece is "list/_piece.html.erb"
# It's necessary to pass `@list` variable so that it knows which one to show
$('#lists').append('<%= j render(partial: 'piece', locals: {list: @list}) %>');
```

Then in `_piece.html.erb`, use a local variable `list` but not `@list` To read:

```
<li><%= list.name %></li>
```

Then your code should be able to work.

Side note: The "piece" template could also be called in the `index` template, or the sidebar list of list, so it will be DRY.

Comment: Didn't work. Now the new action won't work. The append is there to add the new list to the list of lists in the div, why would I want to load the form again? Maybe I shouldn't be using render at all? (I'm new to Rails)

Comment: @bedroomfireflys, yes, good point, you need a partial to render single piece of "list"(not necessarily the "show" template), instead of "new". I was just mislead by you:). No need to change the form. The way of passing variable the same for the show piece template.

Comment: Can you revise your answer?

Comment: @bedroomfireflys, revised.

Comment: It works. I have some questions though. using "render(@list) worked for Ryan Bates in his screencast tutorial, is there a reason why it's not working for me? I just feel like using a partial for this seems like it's added bulk.

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe out of date? Since I browsed the doc but havn't found such usage: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render. For added bulk, no, it's necessary. You can't use `show` as you want to show much more there.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for checking the doc. My next question: Currently, when I click the "add list" button, the button disappears and form field appears in it's place. How would I go about changing the code so that the form appears below the button instead?

Comment: You have code `$('#new_list').remove();` I guess #new_list is the form? Just don't remove it.

Comment: No, that's removing the form field. #new_link is the button div. That code is being called when I submit the new list, not when I click the add list button.

Comment: Sorry, I just updated my code. I left out the 'new.js.erb' file where this behavior is taking place.

Comment: $('#lists').prepend('<%= j render("form") %>'); seems to be working but if I click the add list button again, it generates a second form field under the first one. How do I prevent the button from doing this? I remember there was a way to "disable" elements but I don't remember the syntax.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29000/discussion-between-billy-chan-and-bedroomfireflys)